# Grammar and Spell Checker for C# strings in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've taking lead on a project and the old developers had a lot of spelling problems, I wondered if there was an extension of some kind that would go through all strings in the project and check the spelling and grammar?

Something like grammarly but for Visual Studio 17, I haven't found anything as of yet but I was hoping someone may know of something like this.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Spelling checker for Visual Studio. You can add it to visual studio. But for the grammar check, I haven't met such tool like Grammarly.

[Visual Studio Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EWoodruff.VisualStudioSpellCheckerVS2017andLater)

[Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker)

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EWoodruff.VisualStudioSpellCheckerVS2017andLater#overview) by EWoodruff